# Reviewing for Data in Chrome's Development Tool

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to review if this ".cchatinput" contain any data WITHOUT looking at the webpage's looks by using Chrome's development tool?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, select `$('.ccchatinput')` with the mouse, release the button and hover the mouse cursor over the selection.

Comment: It's important to note that it only works when debugger is active (execution is paused)

Answer (score 0):

You can run queries in the Console tab. That's what it's for, as a "scratch pad" for quick queries.

You can just run `$('.ccchatinput')` there as a command and inspect the results.

---

While debugging, there's also the "Watch" section in the right-hand panel of Sources tab. You can add an expression there, and it will be evaluated every time the debugger pauses execution.

Comment: To add to this, you can also bring up the console from any other tab by hitting <ESC>